# Organize GitLab projects and users into groups

Tags: gitlab

We are moving our version management over to GitLab. While doing so we run into the following question. GitLab allows you to create groups for projects and users. Our wish is to restrict the user's access rights, since there's no need for every developer being able to access the source code of every repository. Our initial idea was to group the projects by client and assign developers to clients. Yet, some projects are worked on by several teams. So we would have to add those team members either to the entire client group or to the specific project itself. Now the main question I run in to is that if a developer leaves the company, we would like to be able to retract the user's permissions from all the company's projects. Yet I don't see a clear and easy way to do this. If the permissions are scattered across groups and projects, we would have to check each and every project to make sure the user is fully removed. It would be really ideal if we could create user groups that are separate from project group. But I don't see this option. How do you organize your projects and users? What are your recommendations to solve these issues?

Comment: I don't know that there's an "easy" way to do this right now, but the Support team built a [GitLab Group leader tool](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support/toolbox/glgl) to get a list of members for a parent group.

It's definitely a real struggle though so I [opened a feature request to list all members in a parent group](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/27074). Please upvote, and/or comment with your use case to increase its visibility and priority.

Comment: You can use the API to remove a user from all your groups using https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#remove-a-member-from-a-group-or-project

Comment: There's also some Terraform provider that would enable you to have all configuration in code.
This is for sure not easy to setup, but you could (re)assign people from projects.